# Image size filters not functioning as expected

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-template

I'm looking to have all product images shown as the `1024x1024` size that is automatically created upon upload. Currently, all images are shown in `master` size.

I have the following line of code, which *should* render as my requested size:

```
<img src="{{ product.featured_image | img_url: '1024x1024' }}" alt="{{ featured_image.alt | escape }}" id="ProductPhotoImg" data-image-position="1">
```

However, this is not the case. For example, I see in Chrome DevTools that an (arbitrary) featured image's intrinsic size is 1754 x 2456, both dimensions of which are larger than 1024. Clearly, it is only rendering the master image.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: You got a link to view?

Comment: Can you confirm if the generated image URL has 1024x1024.jpg at the end? Or just paste it to see what is the end result, since your code is valid.

Comment: Did you tried to determin width and height with CSS properties?

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering if the code you pasted is taken from the place where you are having issues. I think I recall having had similar results if my code was missing the quotes around the size parameter like:

```
<img src="{{ product.featured_image | img_url: 1024x1024 }}" alt="{{ featured_image.alt | escape }}" id="ProductPhotoImg" data-image-position="1">
```